# AWS Serverless vs versioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am wondering about how does entire AWS Serverless feature set work with VCS tools?

I mean, assume I'd like to build a complex HA, scalable system basing as much on serverless tech stack as possible. I would create some VPC, subnents, S3 buckets, Elasticache, Aurora, SNS, SQS, etc... and of course a bunch of Lambdas triggering one another. Naturally that would be efficient (both in terms of performance and cost), I know I could enable CloudWatch, CloudTrail and use AWS X-Ray for debugging.

But what about storing my application in GIT? Should I implement entire setup of my app using `AWS CLI` or is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store your application in GIT with all it's ressources if you use Infrastructure as Code.

Take a look at tools like [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/?nc1=f_ls) and [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/)